# Conexão com o banco fica aberta em método estático?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, static

Tenho a seguinte classe estática disponível para toda a aplicação:

```
public static class MinhaClasse
{
   public static void Salvar(Item meuItem)
   {
       using (MeuEntities db = new MeuEntities())
       {
           db.Item.Add(meuItem);
           db.SaveChanges();
           db.Dispose();
       }
   }
}
```

> Este é apenas um exemplo, mas minha classe precisa necessariamente ser
>   estática.

A dúvida é:
Por ser uma classe estática e possuir conexão com o banco de dados, esta  conexão fica aberta a todo tempo ou apenas é aberta quando chamo `MinhaClasse.Salvar(Item);` ?
Estou usando **Entity Framework**.

Comment: Baseado em experiencia com outro `Framework` penso que é redundante `db.Dispose()` já que `using` automaticamente faria este trabalho.

Portanto, tanto  `db.Dispose()` quanto `using` fechariam a conexão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MeuEntities` é uma classe gerada pelo *Entity Framework*, herdando de de *DbContext*, certo?

## Ciclo de vida da conexão

Usando o *Entity Framework*, você não controla o ciclo de vida da conexão mas sim o ciclo de vida do contexto. Em momentos específicos o contexto vai requisitar uma conexão com o banco para buscar ou persistir entidades.

A conexão física com o banco de dados é gerenciada pelo **ADO.Net**, que mantém um pool de conexões para evitar criar uma nova conexão todas as vezes que o consumidor precisar de uma, com isso ele oferece melhor performance já que criar conexão com o banco de dados tem custo alto.

> Mantenha curta a vida do contexto e deixe a gerência de conexões com o Entity Framework e o ADO.Net que ele usa por baixo.

E isso você já está fazendo já que você cria o contexto apenas para persistir e já se desfaz dele.

## Relação entre a classe ser estática e o ciclo de vida da conexão.

**Não há nenhuma relação.** O escopo do contexto ou fato de você se desfazer dele (seja por invocar o método *dispose* ou seja por instanciá-lo com o *using*) é que vai afetar o ciclo de vida da conexão. O fato de a classe que consome o contexto ser estática não tem nenhuma relação.

Agora, se você declarar o contexto numa variável estática e não se desfizer dele nunca, daí sim você poderá afetar negativamente o ciclo de vida da conexão.

## Por fim

Remova do seu código a chamada ao método ***dispose*** pois o ***using*** serve justamente para garantir esta chamada.

Comment: Ótima resposta. `MeuEntities` está herdando sim de `DbContext`. Muito obrigado, ficou bem claro!

Answer (score 3):

Eu questionaria se realmente precisa que a classe precisa ser estática. Muitas vezes achamos que precisa mas na realidade não precisa. Mas não estou dizendo que isto seja um problema em si.

Eu não sei bem como funcionam essa classe que está usando mas vou confiar que ela abre a conexão. Sei que ela abre algum recurso que precisa ser fechado. E você usou da forma correta, com `using`. A linguagem se encarrega de dispor o recurso quando ele não for mais necessário sem seu código ter que se preocupar com isto.

Então o `Dispose()` usado é desnecessário.

Se a classe `MeuEntities` foi escrita corretamente, a conexão será fechada automaticamente. Como ela deve ter como base algo escrito no EF, ela deve estar fazendo corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

> Por ser uma classe estática e possuir conexão com o banco de dados, esta conexão fica aberta a todo tempo ou apenas é aberta quando chamo `MinhaClasse.Salvar(Item);`?

Não.

[O `Dispose` do `DbContext` chama o `Dispose` da `DbConnection` associada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dispose(v=vs.113).aspx). Significa que, ao final do `using`, a conexão é fechada.

Ou seja, a cada chamada do seu método estático, uma nova conexão é aberta.

Para sistemas Web, isto está correto, já que o ciclo de vida de uma requisição em ASP.NET MVC não conta com conexões persistentes, sejam elas a bancos de dados ou serviços. O Entity Framework apenas segue a mesma premissa, fechando a conexão ao banco quando ela não é usada.